# Python 2.7: the 'replace' method of the 'string' object deprecated

Tags: python

My "workmates" just told me that the *replace* method of the *string* object was deprecated and will be removed in 3.xx.

Is it true? And if so, how can I replace it (with examples)?

Comment: `help(str.replace)` shows no deprecation-note. Can't you just ask your workmates where they got that from?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html) of 3.2 says nothing about that the replace method of the *str* type should be removed. I also don't see any reason why someone should do that.

But the replace function in the [string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) module was removed.

An example:

```
"bla".replace("a", "b")
```

calls the replace method of the *str* type.

```
string.replace("bla", "a", "b")
```

calls the replace function of the *string* module.

Maybe this is what your workmates mixed up. Using the *string* module function is a very, very old way to do this stuff in Python. They are deprecated, beginning with Python 2.0(!). I am not so good in the history of Python, but I guess probably right when they have introduced object-oriented concepts into the language.

Comment: Good answer. I would also say thay `"bla".replace("a", "b") can also be rewritren as str.replace("bla", "a", "b"), and maybe that's the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand those deprecation warnings in http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions, only the functions are deprecated. The methods are not.

E.g., if you use:

```
s = 'test'
string.replace(s, 'est', '')
```

you should replace it with

```
s.replace('est', '')
```

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. Perhaps it should link to a particular version where that page anchor exists.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use this code below:

```
    a = "hello".replace("e", "o")
    print(a)
```

And this likely should be the output:

```
hollo
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow! Please keep in mind when answering questions that your answer needs to add significant knowledge over existing answers, so in this case dmeister has already provided this answer (and it was accepted as working), this answer also fails to mention if .replace is depreciated in 3x+ which was the original question. Thank you, and again welcome to SO!