# How to find and replace multiple lines in text file?

Tags: python, string, file, replace

I am running Python 2.7.

I have three text files: `data.txt`, `find.txt`, and `replace.txt`.  Now, `find.txt` contains several lines that I want to search for in `data.txt` and replace that section with the content in `replace.txt`.  Here is a simple example:

**data.txt**

```
pumpkin
apple
banana
cherry
himalaya
skeleton
apple
banana
cherry
watermelon
fruit
```

**find.txt**

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

**replace.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

So, in the above example, I want to search for all occurences of `apple`, `banana`, and `cherry` in the data and replace those lines with `1,2,3`.

I am having some trouble with the right approach to this as my `data.txt` is about 1MB so I want to be as efficient as possible.  One dumb way is to concatenate everything into one long string and use `replace`, and then output to a new text file so all the line breaks will be restored.

```
import re

data = open("data.txt", 'r')
find = open("find.txt", 'r')
replace = open("replace.txt", 'r')

data_str = ""
find_str = ""
replace_str = "" 

for line in data: # concatenate it into one long string
    data_str += line

for line in find: # concatenate it into one long string
    find_str += line

for line in replace: 
    replace_str += line


new_data = data_str.replace(find, replace)
new_file = open("new_data.txt", "w")
new_file.write(new_data)
```

But this seems so convoluted and inefficient for a large data file like mine.  Also, the `replace` function appears to be deprecated so that's not good.

Another way is to step through the lines and keep a track of which line you found a match.

Something like this:

```
location = 0

LOOP1: 
for find_line in find:
    for i, data_line in enumerate(data).startingAtLine(location):
        if find_line == data_line:
            location = i # found possibility

for idx in range(NUMBER_LINES_IN_FIND):
    if find_line[idx] != data_line[idx+location]  # compare line by line
        #if the subsequent lines don't match, then go back and search again
        goto LOOP1
```

Not fully formed code, I know.  I don't even know if it's possible to search through a file from a certain line on or between certain lines but again, I'm just a bit confused in the logic of it all.  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file is large, you want to `read` and `write` *one line at a time*, so the whole thing isn't loaded into memory at once.

```
# create a dict of find keys and replace values
findlines = open('find.txt').read().split('\n')
replacelines = open('replace.txt').read().split('\n')
find_replace = dict(zip(findlines, replacelines))

with open('data.txt') as data:
    with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as new_data:
        for line in data:
            for key in find_replace:
                if key in line:
                    line = line.replace(key, find_replace[key])
            new_data.write(line)
```

Edit: I changed the code to `read().split('\n')` instead of `readliens()` so `\n` isn't included in the find and replace strings

Comment: Thank you for this! Now, there's one more issue that I forgot to explicitly include in my question that I fear may have been misleading.  If `replace.txt` contained more lines than `find.txt`, the `zip` function would ignore those extra lines.  Now, I still want them to be included so instead of `apple,banana,cherry` to be replaced with `1,2,3`, I want that slot to be replaced with `1,2,3,4,5`.  Is this possible?

Comment: you want *what* slot to be replaced? without a key, there is nothing to replace with it

Comment: Yea, I see what you're saying but what I mean is: in my data I want to be able to replace the lines as determined in the `find.txt` file, `apple,banana,cherry`, with any number of lines.  So if `replace.txt` had 10 more lines than `find.txt`, it would still insert them into the data, making the data list longer.  Or `replace.txt` may be shorter than `find.txt` for that matter.  I hope I'm making sense.  Basically, for my usage, I can't assume that `replace.txt` will have the same number of lines as `find.txt`

Comment: You should probably ask that as a brand NEW question. It's fundamentally different from this one, and not clear in comment form

Answer (score 1):

couple things here:

replace is not deprecated, see this discussion for details:
[Python 2.7: replace method of string object deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267219/python-2-7-replace-method-of-string-object-deprecated)

If you are worried about reading data.txt in to memory all at once, you should be able to just iterate over data.txt one line at a time

```
data = open("data.txt", 'r')
for line in data:
    # fix the line
```

so all that's left is coming up with a whole bunch of find/replace pairs and fixing each line.  Check out the [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function for a handy way to do that

```
find = open("find.txt", 'r').readlines()
replace = open("replace.txt", 'r').readlines()
new_data = open("new_data.txt", 'w')
for find_token, replace_token in zip(find, replace):
    new_line = line.replace(find_token, replace_token)
    new_data.write(new_line + os.linesep)
```

Comment: +1 for correcting my faulty confusion with the string module `replace` deprecation, not the string type `replace` deprecation.  So, `replace` is not being deprecated. That is good!  Thank you.