# How to find and replace X lines in one text file with Y lines in another text file?

Tags: python, string, file, replace

I asked this question: [How to find and replace multiple lines in text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637282/how-to-find-and-replace-multiple-lines-in-text-file/21637591?noredirect=1#21637591)
but was ultimately unclear in my question so I'm asking another one to be more specific.

I have Python 2.7.

I have three text files, `data.txt`, `find.txt` and `replace.txt`.

`data.txt` is about 1MB large file with several thousand lines.  Now, I have a `find.txt` file containing X number of lines that I want to find in `data.txt` and replace with Y number of lines in `replace.txt`  X and Y may be the same number, or it may not.

For example:

**data.txt**

```
pumpkin
apple
banana
cherry
himalaya
skeleton
apple
banana
cherry
watermelon
fruit
```

**find.txt**

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

**replace.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So, in the above example, I want to search for all occurences of `apple`, `banana`, and `cherry` in the data and insert `1,2,3,4,5` in its place.

So, the resulting `data.txt` would look like:

```
pumpkin
1
2
3
4
5
himalaya
skeleton
1
2
3
4
5
watermelon
fruit
```

Or, if the number of lines in `replace.txt` were less than that of `find.txt`:

```
pumpkin
1
2
himalaya
skeleton
1
2
watermelon
fruit
```

I am having some trouble with the right approach to this as my `data.txt` is about 1MB so I want to be as efficient as possible.  One dumb way is to concatenate everything into one long string and use `replace`, and then output to a new text file so all the line breaks will be restored.

```
data = open("data.txt", 'r')
find = open("find.txt", 'r')
replace = open("replace.txt", 'r')

data_str = ""
find_str = ""
replace_str = "" 

for line in data: # concatenate it into one long string
    data_str += line

for line in find: # concatenate it into one long string
    find_str += line

for line in replace: 
    replace_str += line


new_data = data_str.replace(find, replace)
new_file = open("new_data.txt", "w")
new_file.write(new_data)
```

But this seems so convoluted and inefficient for a large data file like mine.

The pseudo-code for something that I would like to see:

Something like this:

```
(x,y) = find_lines(data.txt, find.txt) # returns line numbers in data.txt that contains find.txt
replace_data_between(x, y, data.txt, replace.txt) # replaces the data between lines x and y with replace.txt

def find_lines(...):
    location = 0

    LOOP1: 
    for find_line in find:
        for i, data_line in enumerate(data).startingAtLine(location):
            if find_line == data_line:
                location = i # found possibility

    for idx in range(NUMBER_LINES_IN_FIND):
        if find_line[idx] != data_line[idx+location]  # compare line by line
            #if the subsequent lines don't match, then go back and search again
            goto LOOP1
```

As you can see, I am having trouble with the logic of this all.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: go through `find.txt` and `replace.txt` together, make a lookup `dict`.  Then go through `data.txt` and replace each line with its value in the lookup dict, if it's there.  You need to be more specific on the layout of `find` and `replace.txt` to get more specific help than that.

Comment: without a 1:1 mapping, what *is* the mapping of `find` to `replace`? instead of a text file, can you give us a python object?

Comment: what do you want to happen when X and Y are not the same? What happens when X > Y and when X < Y? Also, if you have made attempts at this already, please share your code

Comment: @Totem: Thanks for your comments.  I edited my question so I hope that gives more information.

Comment: @roippi: Thanks for your comments. I edited my question so I hope that gives more information.

Comment: @noblerare do the lines you want to find always come all together like that?

Comment: @Totem: yes, the `find.txt` file will contain line-by-line, the exact lines that I want to find and replace

Comment: @noblerare and in the data.txt file? Do they always appear together just like in find.txt?

Comment: @Totem: Yes they do but they must match exactly.  In other words, there may be a line of `apple` followed by `foobar` in which case it _doesn't_ match the lines in `find.txt` (using the example above).  So, if I had `data.txt` printed out onto paper and I had a knife, I want to find all exact lines in `find.txt`, cut them out and replace them with `replace.txt`.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are small enough to do this in ram...

I would first map the find:replace relationship:

```
find_replace_dict = {find_string:replace_string}
```

then i would walk through the data file...

```
of = open('output_file','wt')
for line in data_file:
    if line in find_replace_dict.keys():
        of.write(find_replace_dict[line])
    else:
        of.write(line)
of.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but some of the comments that I got asked me to be more specific in my question so I edited the question.